# How to put Messsenger on top of full screen video?

Tags: flash

Just as the title says, how can I use messenger or any chat client while i'm watching video in browser with full screen? I can use gtalk when watching youtube video in full screen in Windows, but can't figure out how to put chat window on full screen video using alt-tab.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu just Right-Click on the Title Bar of the Chat Client window and select the option "Always On Top". The Window will now remain on Top of all other Windows so you can Fullscreen a Video and still continue to chat.

EDIT: Oh I see. The problem here is Flash. Flash puts itself on top of everything else no matter what. The only way around that is to not use the Flash Player's Fullscreen button but instead zoom in on the player while it's still in the browser window. In Firefox `CTRL+-` Zooms Out, `CTRL+ +` Zooms In, and `CTRL+0` Returns to Default Zoom.

Comment: yes, i tried it before but it doesn't work. I click "Always on Top", then make the video full screen. After that I press alt-tab to bring up the chat window, it would exit out the full screen and just the chat window on top of the normal browser window

Comment: Oh I see. The problem here is Flash. Flash puts itself on top of everything else no matter what. The only way around that is to not use the Flash players Fullscreen button but instead zoom in on the player while it's still in the browser window. In Firefox `CTRL+-` Zooms Out, `CTRL+ +` Zooms In, and `CTRL+0` Returns to Default Zoom.

Comment: I can upvote if you edit your answer though this is not really a fix :). That suggestion works almost as good as a full screen.

Comment: No Prob. In the future you should remember to mention that what you're doing involves something like Flash or Java because that can really change what the answer is. Like what happened here.

Comment: Instead of using flash you could try using a.) [minitube](http://flavio.tordini.org/minitube), b.) [youtube in HTML5 mode](https://www.youtube.com/html5?gl=DE&hl=de)

Comment: True, HTML5 Youtube would work but a lot of videos (ie: Ad supported) require Flash.